# AWS S3 storing images from camera

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I have a web application made using php and laravel and you can see it at www.dailywodtracker.com . You'd have to register to see it but basically I have a portion to choose photo for the workout from your camera and if I use the selfie camera it loads, and if I use the outer camera it breaks the code.  So I guess certain size images are not loading.  Any ideas on how I can fix this problem?  Comes back in my console log as: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: What is the size of the picture? Also do you upload it directly to S3 from client?

Comment: It gets uploaded directly from the client and it seems that anything about 8 megapixel camera crashes it.

Comment: So I've tested it again and if I am testing through a local host I can shove giant giant images in there, it's just from a phones camera where it breaks.

Comment: If I use the same image on my local server that works on my deployed website, it crashes it.  Does it have something to do with heroku possibly?